# Кэширование базы MYSQL

Tags: mysql, кэширование

У меня есть очень большая база mysql. для скорости работы посоветовали сделать кэширование. и да, если 1 раз запросы исполнились, второй раз они грузятся быстро. но через некоторое время (пару часов) они снова долго грузятся. Такое ощущение, что кэш очистился.

С чем это может быть связано? Есть какой то параметр, отвечающий за время жизни кэша?

Comment: А большая - это какого размера. Может она вся в кеш не влезает и какая нибудь объемная операция временами вытесняет из кеша все остальное.

Comment: Я как то заметил что у меня дисковый ввод вывод начал конкретно расти. оказалось в системе был один запрос, который большую таблицу проходил полным сканированием. проблем было не заметно, пока она целиком влезала в кеш, как только она перестала этот запрос начисто вытеснял из кеша все остальное и начало таблицы то же, поэтому следующий запрос начинал все заново, вытесняя началом таблицы блоки, которые ему еще предстояло читать

Comment: большая - это по 50 - 100 миллионов записей. точный вес не скажу (это база текдока)

Comment: Ну чудес не бывает, если вся БД в кеш целиком не влезает, то конечно любые читаемые данные вытесняют предыдущие, как только кеш заполняется. И один кривой запрос в системе (делающий full scan по таблице) "очистит" кеш. надо смотреть все запросы в системе, искать долгие, разбираться с их планами выполнения, оптимизировать. Начать с долгих запросов https://habrahabr.ru/post/31072/

Comment: а есть возможность как то проверить: помещается вся база или нет?

Comment: база весит около 112 Gb

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что кеш у вас меньше 112 Гб. Кстати, о каком кеше идет речь. в MySQL есть еще кеш запросов ... И в любом случае запросы смотреть все равно надо, любой full scan большой таблицы гарантированно вытеснит все остальное. любой параметр, непосредственно подставляемый в текст запроса (а не через bind параметра) очень быстро забьет весь кеш запросов

Comment: да, я и говорю именно о кэше запросов

Comment: Кроме того, я думаю вы же знаете, что любой запрос на изменение любой таблицы, участвующей в кешированном запросе очистит кеш. У вас действительно за 2 часа ничего не изменяется ни в одной из таблиц, участвующих в интересующих вас запросах ?

Comment: Лично я бы вообще не полагался на долговременное сохранение кеша БД, даже если знаю наизусть все до единого запросы, работающие в БД. Для таких целей обычно используются внешние системы кеширования, вроде memcached

Comment: я не смог настроить memcached( по поводу изменения данных - они точно не меняются, это статические табдицы

Comment: вот статью небольшую нашел, https://habrahabr.ru/post/41166/ там написано как смотреть статистику по работе кеша. по ней скорее всего можно понять что происходит. А вообще если данные не меняются и запрос собирающий какой нибудь агрегат или что вы там кешируете, может просто записать результаты этой выборки в другую таблицу